# python selenium click at current position

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a drop down menu that i need to click to activate. Elements of dropdown are not exposed in the html and therefor cannot be found to click on.  So once dropdown is activated I key up to the option I want and now I just need a single mouse click at that position but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

nextButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rendererColorClassifyMethodDropdown"]')
nextButton.click()

nextButton.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
nextButton.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
nextButton.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
nextButton.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
nextButton.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
AC.click()
```

This results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

the scroll up is working as I can see monitoring the python commands but I can't click the option once I'm there. Using `nextButton.click()` just resets the dropdown.

Here is the html that when clicked invokes the dropdown:

```
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-required="true" tabindex="0" id="rendererColorClassifyMethodDropdown" value="" aria-invalid="false" readonly="" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

The tag immediately following it is:

```
<input type="hidden" value="Natural Breaks">
```

When i scroll with arrow keys the value of the second tag changes to whatever the scrolled value currently is bu there is no way to find the html element of the clickable value in the actual dropdown display.

Here is a pic:
[image]

Comment: _Elements of dropdown are not exposed in the html and therefor cannot be found to click on._ What do you mean? How can they be interacted with otherwise?

Comment: It is some weird dijit property. I added the html tag for the drop down menu and what it displays as current value. There are no lists displayed in html with values that I can see.

Comment: Nevermind. I can just use enter I found out.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question in case someone else finds themselves in this situation and are ready to throw their laptop through the window.

Don't bother with the click. Use "Enter"

```
nextButton.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
nextButton.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
nextButton.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
nextButton.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
nextButton.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
nextButton.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```